# Swift 3: make button present ViewController, how?

Tags: ios, swift3, screen

I would like my button to reshow the user my on boarding screen since it includes some important instructions to my app.
The first time I show my onboarding screen is after the first launch;
My current function looks like this:

```
@IBAction func anleitung(sender: RoundButtons) {

    let appDelegate = AppDelegate()
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(OnboardingScreen(), animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

This is actually like the 4th way I tried this, but, apparently, none of them worked. Do you know how to do that?

Thanks for having a look! Have a great day!

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: tried that but didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@IBAction func anleitung(sender: RoundButtons) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(OnboardingScreen(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```